# Azure blob copy in cloud

Tags: azure, blob, azure-blob-storage

In aws, the "upload-part-copy" has option of byte ranges. If I wanted to copy portions of two objects to a new object within the cloud, I can copy using the "upload-part-copy" command.

I could not find any such method or mechanism to copy portions of blobs to a new blob in Azure. I tried AzCopy. But it does not have any option to select some portion of blob.

Can anyone please help me if there is any method like that.

Answer (score 1):

> Can anyone please help me if there is any method like that.

As of today, this feature is not there in Azure Blob Storage. A copy operation copies the entire source blob to destination blob.

A workaround would be to download the byte ranges (blocks) from the source blobs on your local machine and then create a new blob by uploading these blocks.

If you were using [`Blob Service REST API`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/fileservices/blob-service-rest-api), here would be the operations you would need to perform:

1. [`Read Source Blob 1`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/fileservices/get-blob) by specifying the range in `Range` or `x-ms-range` request header you would like to read. Store the data fetched somewhere in your application.
2. Repeat the same for Source Blob 2.
3. Now create a new blob by uploading the data fetched for 1st source blob using [`Put Block`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/fileservices/put-block).
4. Repeat the same for 2nd source blob.
5. Create the destination blob by [committing block list](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/fileservices/put-block-list).