# Copy File between azure blobs containers

Tags: node.js, typescript, azure, azure-blob-storage

I'm using the @azure/storage-blob package to manipulate files in Azure.

In the same Azure storage account I have two storage containers i.e. source and destination.

What I'm trying to do is copy a file located in the source container to the destination container without having to download the file.

I'm currently downloading to a buffer and uploading to the destination.

Is there any way to do this directly?

```
const blobServiceClient = BlobServiceClient.fromConnectionString(BLOB_CONNECTION_STRING);

const sourceContainerClient = blobServiceClient.getContainerClient(SOURCE_CONTAINER_NAME);
const sourceBlockBlobClient = sourceContainerClient.getBlockBlobClient(filename);

const destinationContainerClient = blobServiceClient.getContainerClient(DESTINATION_CONTAINER_NAME);
const destinationBlockBlobClient = finalContainerClient.getBlockBlobClient(filename);

const sourceFileBuffer = await sourceBlockBlobClient.downloadToBuffer();
destinationBlockBlobClient.uploadData(sourceFileBuffer);
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Azure blob copy in cloud](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41443524/azure-blob-copy-in-cloud)

Comment: @CSharpRocks its almost how I'm doing it right now. I mean, I'm downloading from one container and uploading to the other.
I was hoping to find a solution to have this process happen inside the azure storage, without the need to download/upload the file at runtime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I`ve solved the problem with the following code:

```
const blobServiceClient = BlobServiceClient.fromConnectionString(BLOB_CONNECTION_STRING);

const sourceContainerClient = blobServiceClient.getContainerClient(SOURCE_CONTAINER_NAME);
const sourceBlockBlobClient = sourceContainerClient.getBlockBlobClient(filename);

const destinationContainerClient = blobServiceClient.getContainerClient(DESTINATION_CONTAINER_NAME);
const destinationBlockBlobClient = finalContainerClient.getBlockBlobClient(filename);

// const sourceFileBuffer = await sourceBlockBlobClient.downloadToBuffer();
// destinationBlockBlobClient.uploadData(sourceFileBuffer);

await destinationBlockBlobClient.syncCopyFromURL(`${sourceBlockBlobClient.url}?${sasToken}`);
```

Using the `syncCopyFromUrl` function I did just pass an URL and the file was copied correctly and faster.
In my scenario, I've needed to generate a `sasToken` to ensure the file was accessible for copying.

Answer (score 0):

> Copy File between Azure blobs containers.

You can use the below code to copy a file from one container to another container using javascript SDK.

**Code:**

```
const { BlobServiceClient } = require('@azure/storage-blob');

const CONNECTION_STRING = '<Your-connection -string>';
const SOURCE_CONTAINER_NAME = 'test'; //<your-source-container-name>
const DESTINATION_CONTAINER_NAME = 'test1'; //<Your-destination-container-name>
const filename = 'sample012.txt';

async function copyFile() {
  const blobServiceClient = BlobServiceClient.fromConnectionString(CONNECTION_STRING);

  const sourceContainerClient = blobServiceClient.getContainerClient(SOURCE_CONTAINER_NAME);
  const sourceBlockBlobClient = sourceContainerClient.getBlockBlobClient(filename);

  const destinationContainerClient = blobServiceClient.getContainerClient(DESTINATION_CONTAINER_NAME);
  const destinationBlockBlobClient = destinationContainerClient.getBlockBlobClient(filename);

  const sourceBlobUrl = sourceBlockBlobClient.url;
  await destinationBlockBlobClient.startCopyFromURL(sourceBlobUrl);

  console.log(`File ${filename} copied from ${SOURCE_CONTAINER_NAME} to ${DESTINATION_CONTAINER_NAME}`);
}

copyFile().catch((err) => {
  console.error('Error:', err.message);
})
```

**Output:**

```
File sample012.txt copied from test to test1
```

[image]

**Portal:**
[image]

**Reference:**

[Get started with Azure Blob Storage and JavaScript - Azure Storage | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-blob-javascript-get-started?tabs=azure-ad)

Comment: It seems that i can't call the function startCopyFromURL because it's private and only accessible from within class BlobClient